# GRASS v.proj "Error in pj_do_transform"

Tags: grass-gis, windows

When I try to use v.proj to reproject my map from OSGB to GoogleMaps coord system I get this error....

```
Reprojecting primitives:
pj_transform() failed: failed to load datum shift file
ERROR: Error in pj_do_transform
```

Can someone confirm I not doing something stupid to cause this error please ...

My file structure is...

```
e:\work\grass\GB\mapset1
e:\work\grass\UK_EPSG900913\mapset1
```

I.e. 'mapset1' folders contain the 'vector' and 'dbf' directories etc.

So I have two locations 'GB' and 'UK_EPSG900913'
The projections are set to OSGB and epsg900913 respectively.

I have a map in the 'GB' location that I wish to reproject to epsg900913
I understand that to do this I choose the location as 'UK_EPSG900913' and 'mapset1' when I launch GRASS
and then I type this command...

```
v.proj input=scot location=GB mapset=mapset1 output=scot1
```

And then a map should appear in my 'UK_EPSG900913/mapset1/vector' folder.

Is my understanding of how to re-project correct? If so can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, GRASS 6.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ticket may have some explanations:

https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/1452

Comment: Thanks @markusN. It work fine when I tried it on Ubuntu. I seem to be getting quite a few things that dont work on Windows 7 but do work on Ubuntu. So I think I'll move over to Ubuntu for GRASS.

Comment: Some things have been improved and will appear in GRASS 6.4.3.